# Extended Events SQL Server Select Query

Tags: sql-server, ssms, extended-events

Which XEvents fire on simple select * from table query ? 
I want to test something and can't find easily testable XEvent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sql_batch_starting` and `sql_batch_completed` events will capture an ad-hoc query. Parameterized queries can be captured with `rpc_starting` and `rpc_completed`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have been looking for !